# Makefile for installing an OCaml library

Tags: makefile, debian, ocaml

What are the things I need in my `install` and `uninstall` targets in a `Makefile` for an OCaml library in order to make it play nicely with the rest of the installation, work seamlessly with `ocamlfind` and so on? Basically to be a "good citizen". I am not interested in GODI at the present time. Thanks!

Comment: It's OCaml bindings to a C library which can be assumed to exist, FWIW.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

META files for ocamlfind are easy to write (basically, look for a META in another ocaml project you know¹, copy it and make the corresponding changes), and they will give you ocamlfind integration, with in particular easy support for post-build installation and desinstallation (using `ocamlfind install` and `ocamlfind remove`). You should begin with that.

¹: for example I take inspiration from [batteries's META](https://github.com/ocaml-batteries-team/batteries-included/blob/master/META.in).

The building part of the Makefile is more tricky, their are numerous solutions (OCamlMakefile, OMake, ocamlbuild, plain Makefile, etc.) with varying strenghts and weaknesses. If you project is simple enough I would recommend ocamlbuild that takes care of a lot of the dependency tracking by itself.

You may also use [Oasis](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/index.php), which is a relatively new tools that builds on ocamlbuild and ocamlfind and seeks to provide a unified configuration file for pre-build configuration and various building and deployment (of your program, your software libraries if any, accompanying data or documentation...). It's not yet a mature project (and its little brother Oasis-DB isn't released yet), but I encourage you to give it a try if you have time. It's a bit more complex than META, as it does more in the end, so building the META first is still a good step.

Finally, you said you weren't interested in Godi (Godi is a very good system, and in some cases (eg. BSD etc.) it's a premium choice to have a good OCaml installation), but in case you may still be interested in [Godiva](http://projects.phauna.org/godiva/), a tool to help the building of GODI packages. I have never used it myself, though.

Comment: I mean nothing against GODI - just it's out of scope for me right now. I am using a plain old-fashioned Makefile right now (as I also have C code to compile). So the process is, create a META file, then get ocamlfind to do the actual work on my behalf?

Comment: For the installation/desinstallation in the system, and to make it easy for other programmers to use your library, yes, `ocamlfind` is what you need. Basically you just give `ocamlfind install` your META file and the list of the (compiled, .mli, etc.) files that you want installed in the ocaml library directory, and you're done.

Answer (score 4):

I don't use makefiles but ocamlbuild and a shell script to install the software I [distribute](http://erratique.ch/software). Debian people did packages for my software with these scripts without problems. So you may want to check them out since they correspond to some of their requirements (e.g. separate targets for byte and native code).

You may also want to have a look
to their [packaging policy](http://pkg-ocaml-maint.alioth.debian.org/ocaml_packaging_policy.html/index.html), though I don't know if this document is still up to date.

Don't forget to add a META file for ocamlfind. And you may also want to include an _oasis file for the upcoming [oasis-db](http://oasis.forge.ocamlcore.org/oasis-db.html) project (not yet done in the software I distribute).